# HTML5 canvas text-shadow equivalent?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I'm attempting to create the same effect I can create in css's text-shadow, with HTML5's canvas.

I can do this with CSS:

```
font: 36px Impact;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000,
            -2px -2px 2px #000,
             2px -2px 2px #000,
            -2px 2px 2px #000,
             2px -2px 2px #000,
             2px 2px 2px #000,
            -2px -2px 0 #000,
             2px -2px 0 #000,
            -2px 2px 0 #000,
             2px -2px 0 #000;
```

Which creates characters that look like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/LBZKxL9.png]

But with HTML5's canvas, the stroke is too thin, and the shadows don't allow me to specify more than one, unlike text-shadow.

Has anyone figured out how to accomplish this?

Comment: What is the canvas code that you have tried?

Comment: Please share with us the code you have used so far so we can look at the problem.

Answer (score 31):

The html canvas command to apply shadows to text (or any drawing) is `context.shadowBlur`

[image]

Here's a starting spot towards your shadowed text effect:

Make sure you fill the text after stroking it or else the shadow will intrude into the fill.

```
ctx.font="75px verdana";
ctx.shadowColor="black";
ctx.shadowBlur=7;
ctx.lineWidth=5;
ctx.strokeText("HELLO",25,100);
ctx.shadowBlur=0;
ctx.fillStyle="white";
ctx.fillText("HELLO",25,100);
```

Comment: While this was helpful, it was also a little bit misleading. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/shadowBlur

Comment: You don't need to stroke the text, just fill it.

Answer (score 1):

You said the stroke is too thin, have you tried increasing the context's lineWidth property? I think a value of 4 with a shadow would be an appropriate value to match your image.

To draw multiple shadows in an HTML5 canvas, you could draw the element multiple times in the same place, with a different shadow each time.

Comment: so I've set my lineWidth to 4 and it's pretty close, but I don't know what shadow to give it. Here's my code: 


  context.fillStyle = 'white';
  context.strokeStyle = 'black';
  context.lineWidth = 4;
  var fontSize = (canvas.height / 8);
  context.font = fontSize + 'px Impact';
  context.textAlign = 'center';